# How to send different emails based on the different order status in magento admin?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In my magento I have many options for the order status in admin panel.

I want to send different custom email templates based on the order status change.By default we have a common email template in which we can change the content only.

How can I do this?

Please help.

[image: Various Order Status]

Comment: Muk, are you want to send   from only order comments ??

Comment: @AmitBera Is this possible to send the comments with different email templates for different order status?

Comment: yes...only working from this section ..

Comment: @AmitBera Could you please share some tutorial or code for the same.